# Помогите разобраться в проблеме с выводом информации из mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Новичок в PHP. Пытался сделать вывод строки из БД, а в итоге ничего (пустая страница).

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydatabase");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id`= '1'");
if($sql) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
          $name=$row["title"];
        echo $name;
      }
}
else {
    print mysqli_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: Может быть у вас запрос вернул 0 записей. И `print mysqli_error($mysqli);`. И поле `id` у вас точно содержит строку, а не число?

Comment: Записи в БД есть, проверял и с другими параметрами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка тут:

```
$name=$row["title"];
```

замените на

```
$name=$row[0];
```

функция `mysqli_fetch_row` возвращает не ассоциативный массив, а индексированный.

Уточню: что если хотите использовать ассоциативный массив, то следует использовать функцию `mysqli_fetch_assoc` ( http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php )